# Calculations with tensors give two different results from seemingly equivalent paths:

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, spinors

$\require{cancel}$
I want to calculate some operators in the context of Metric-Affine-Gravity: specifically spinors. I will work in tangent space, where all greek ($\mu,\nu,..$) indices are cast into latin ones ($a,b,..$) via use of tetrads (for tensors) and with the appropriate rules for other indexed quantities (like connections).
Define the covariant derivative$\nabla_c=\partial_c+\tfrac{1}{2}\omega_{abc}\sigma^{ab} $ with $\sigma^{ab}=\tfrac{1}{4}[\gamma^a,\gamma^b]\equiv\tfrac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}$ so that
$\omega_{abc}={\overset{\phantom{.}\circ}{\omega}}_{abc}+\Omega_{abc}$ is a general spin connection on spinors assumed to be metric compatible only, and thus has torsion. Here ${\overset{\phantom{.}\circ}{\omega}}$  and $\Omega$ are the tangent space equivalents of christoffel symbols and contortion respectively (see [Wikipedia's page on contorsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contorsion_tensor) for the spacetime indexed versions of them). So we can split $\nabla=\overset{\circ}{\nabla}+\tfrac{1}{4}\Omega$
I want to calculate the following term (considering $\gamma^c$ are covariantly conserved)
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
 {\cancel{\nabla}}{\cancel{\nabla}}&=\gamma^c\gamma^d\nabla_c\nabla_d=\Big( \tfrac{1}{2}\{\gamma^c,\gamma^d\} +\tfrac{1}{2}[\gamma^c,\gamma^d] \Big)\nabla_c\nabla_d=\\
    &=\nabla_c\nabla^c+\tfrac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}[\nabla_c,\nabla_d]
\end{split}
\end{align}
now,
$\phantom{cd}\nabla_c\nabla^c={\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}\vphantom{A}^c+\tfrac{1}{4}({\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c\Omega^c+\Omega^c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c)+\tfrac{1}{16}\Omega_c\Omega^c $
The curvature 2-form is: $ \phantom{b} R(X,Y)Z=[\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]Z-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z\phantom{cb} $, so when applied to spinors, this becomes the commutator of covariant derivatives $\nabla_c$ minus the torsion part $\phantom{cb}{\Omega_{ab}}^c-{\Omega_{ba}}^c={T^a}_{bc}$ coming from $\Omega$ : so $\phantom{b}\tfrac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}[\nabla_c,\nabla_d]=\tfrac{1}{8}\gamma^{cd}R_{abcd}\gamma^{ab}+\tfrac{1}{8}\gamma^{ab}{T^c}_{ab}\nabla_c \phantom{b}$
$ \phantom{b}R_{abcd}=\partial_c\omega_{abd}+\omega_{axc}{\omega^x}_{bd}-c\leftrightarrow d $. Substituting $\omega={\overset{\phantom{.}\circ}{\omega}}+\Omega$ and calling $\Omega_{abc}\gamma^{ab}\equiv\Omega_c$,
$\phantom{cb} \tfrac{1}{8}\gamma^{cd}R_{abcd}\gamma^{ab}=\tfrac{1}{8}\gamma^{cd}\overset{\circ}{R}_{abcd}\gamma^{ab}+\tfrac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c\Omega_d+\tfrac{1}{8}\gamma^{cd}\Omega_{axc}{\Omega^x}_{bd}\gamma^{ab} $
Had we substituted $\nabla={\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}+\tfrac{1}{4}\Omega$ in the first equation, we would have gotten
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
 (\overset{\circ}{\cancel{\nabla}}+\tfrac{1}{4}\cancel{\Omega})(\overset{\circ}{\cancel{\nabla}}+\tfrac{1}{4}\cancel{\Omega})&=\overset{\circ}{\cancel{\nabla}}\cancel{\nabla}+\tfrac{1}{4}(\overset{\circ}{\cancel{\nabla}}\cancel{\Omega}+\cancel{\Omega}\overset{\circ}{\cancel{\nabla}})+\tfrac{1}{16}\cancel{\Omega}\cancel{\Omega}=\\
    &={\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}^c+\tfrac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}[{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c,{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_d]+\tfrac{1}{16}\Omega_c\Omega^c\\
    &+\tfrac{1}{4}({\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c\Omega^c+\Omega^c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c+\gamma^{cd}({\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c\Omega_d+\Omega_c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_d))
\end{split}
\end{align}
This time, $\phantom{cd}\tfrac{1}{2}\gamma^{cd}[{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c,{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_d]$ is simply $\tfrac{1}{8}\gamma^{cd}\overset{\circ}{R}_{abcd}\gamma^{ab}$ because ${\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}$ has no torsion. In the end, we have 
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
    {\cancel{\nabla}}{\cancel{\nabla}}&={\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}\vphantom{A}^c+\tfrac{1}{4}({\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c\Omega^c+\Omega^c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c)+\tfrac{1}{16}\Omega_c\Omega^c +\\
    &+\tfrac{1}{8}\gamma^{cd}\overset{\circ}{R}_{abcd}\gamma^{ab}+\tfrac{1}{4}\gamma^{cd}{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c\Omega_d+\\
    &+\tfrac{1}{16}\gamma^{cd}\Omega_{axc}{\Omega^x}_{bd}\gamma^{ab}+\tfrac{1}{4}\Omega^c\nabla_c \phantom{b} \\
    \neq(\overset{\circ}{\cancel{\nabla}}+\tfrac{1}{4}\cancel{\Omega})(\overset{\circ}{\cancel{\nabla}}+\tfrac{1}{4}\cancel{\Omega})&={\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}^c+\tfrac{1}{4}({\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c\Omega^c+\Omega^c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c)+\tfrac{1}{16}\Omega_c\Omega^c+\\
    &+\tfrac{1}{8}\gamma^{cd}\overset{\circ}{R}_{abcd}\gamma^{ab}+\tfrac{1}{4}\gamma^{cd}({\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_c\Omega_d+\Omega_c{\overset{\circ}{\nabla}}_d)
\end{split}
\end{align}
so, what have I not understood, or what am I doing wrong? Algebraically this all seems to make sense to me.
One error could be the extra torsion term (last term in the first expansion) from the commutator of $\nabla$s, but that would still not account for the extra $\gamma^{cd} \nabla_c \Omega_d$ and $\gamma\Omega\Omega\gamma$ terms